# How do you empty an array in Axapta 3.0?

Tags: arrays, axapta

Can someone please detail how to empty an array in Axapta 3.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To free an Array object, just assign null to it:

```
Array myArray = new Array(Types::Integer);
;
myArray = null; //remove reference to Array so it will be garbage collected
```

To reset all elements of an array type, assign a value to element 0:

```
int myArray[10];
;
myArray[0]=0; //reset all elements of the array to their default value
```

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa653716.aspx

> n X++, item zero[0] is used to clear the array! Assigning a value to
>   index 0 in an array resets all elements in the array to the default
>   value. For example,
>
> intArray[0] = 0; //Resets all elements in intArray